# Properly captioning aspect fit images

Tags: swift, image, imageview, position

I am looking for the proper way to add a caption to the top and bottom of any image in an imageview set to aspect fit. Seems simple enough, but the textbox doesnt seem to move most of the time and ends up in the center other times. Here is an example of a formula I tried for the top caption.

```
mainTextBox.center.y = mainImageView.center.y + (mainImageView.image!.size.height / 2) - (mainTextBox.frame.size.height / 2)
```

Updated with help from Vandan Patel:

I have also tried manually setting constraints manually buy receive an error

```
    let titleLabelWidth = NSLayoutConstraint(item: mainTextBox, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, multiplier: 0.9, constant: 0)
    let titleLabelCenterX = NSLayoutConstraint(item: mainTextBox, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    let titleLabelCenterY = NSLayoutConstraint(item: mainTextBox, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let titleLabelHeight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: mainTextBox, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, multiplier: 0.9, constant: 0)
    mainTextBox.addConstraints([titleLabelWidth, titleLabelCenterX, titleLabelCenterY, titleLabelHeight])
```

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:mult‌​iplier:constant:]: A multiplier of 0 or a nil second item together with a location for the first attribute creates an illegal constraint of a location equal to a constant. Location attributes must be specified in pairs'

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?[image]

```
//title-Label Constraints

let titleLabelWidth = NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: blurEffectView, attribute: .width, multiplier: 0.9, constant: 0)
let titleLabelCenterX = NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: blurEffectView, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let titleLabelCenterY = NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: blurEffectView, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let titleLabelHeight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: blurEffectView, attribute: .height, multiplier: 0.9, constant: 0)

self.addConstraints([titleLabelWidth, titleLabelCenterX, titleLabelCenterY, titleLabelHeight])
```

Comment: That is a great example!

Comment: So for that, you have to assign a label, and add constraints to it. Since I was working with collectionView, storyboard wasn't too helpful, so i did it programmatically.

Comment: Will the caption move when the image size changes? Could you provide a code example?

Comment: Yes, it should. Set your constraints to the bottom of the image, so doesn't matter what size or where the image goes, it would stick there. This is how I set constraints to the titleLabel (Miss Gomez in this case)

Comment: I have edited my answer. I don't know why StackOverflow doesn't recognize my code, it's in the weird format, but I hope it helps. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you for the example, but I am still having a bit of trouble: 
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:]: A multiplier of 0 or a nil second item together with a location for the first attribute creates an illegal constraint of a location equal to a constant. Location attributes must be specified in pairs'

Comment: You are not setting your constraints properly. I had the same trouble, if you spend some time and think about it, it should be fine. If I read it right, the error shows multiplier of 0. If you are using multiplier of 0 anywhere in your constraint, that would be wrong

Comment: All my other constraints are set with the GUI, could that be causing the issue? It also looks like I am on a newer version of swift, so I looked around and made a few tweaks. Maybe I updated it incorrectly

Comment: It's hard to tell. I wish I could see your code, but yes, when I set constraint programmatically, I prefer to set it for the whole view just for the sake of control and consistency. When I manage something through code, I wouldn't use storyboard to set constraints. But I am not sure if it would cause any problems.

Comment: Great advice, I have updated my question and I will do some more research. Thank you!

Comment: Let me know if you have any further questions, I would be happy to help.